# WPF's DataGrid Sort Descriptions works only for static instances

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, observablecollection

I have a problem with sorting `DataGrid` items using `SortDescriptions`.
I had a `static` `ObservableCollection` that stored my data and after binding that collection to the `DataGrid` I was able to sort the items ascendingly by using `SortDescription`.
After a while I needed to change my code - a `static` instance of that collection was no longer sensible. After making those changes I've built the same `DataGrid` view but sorting the items was no longer working.

---

I need to create a `DataGrid` on `WPF` that would store my application's history records.
For that, I created some classes to be used as history records and then I bound that data to my `DataGrid`. Becuase those are historical records, I would like them to be shown to the user in an ascending order. Meaning the last item I've added will be shown at the very top.

This is my `HistoryRecord` class:

```
public class HistoryRecord {
    public TransactionSender Sender { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
}
```

I've created a `History` class with an observable collection, as follows:

```
public static class History {
    public static ObservableCollection<HistoryRecord> UserHistory { get; set; } =
        new ObservableCollection<HistoryRecord>();
}
```

I chose to use an observable collection because that way I will be able to update the `DataGrid` more easily.

This is my `xaml` code for the `DataGrid` at my history tab:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="HistoryGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True" >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Sender" Binding="{Binding Sender}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Description" Binding="{Binding Description}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Timestamp" Binding="{Binding Timestamp}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

This is my `C# code` for the history tab:

```
public partial class HistoryTab : UserControl {
    public HistoryTab() {
        InitializeComponent();
        HistoryGrid.ItemsSource = History.UserHistory;
        HistoryGrid.Items.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Timestamp", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
        HistoryGrid.Items.Refresh();
    }
}
```

---

The code above works just fine. It does sort my items ascendingly.
Last week I needed to change my code a little bit.
Up until now, it was fine to have a static `History` class but now I need to create multiple instances of that `History` class for several things.

That being said, the app as a whole still has a unified history record.
In order to save that unified history record I created a new class named `HistoryUtil`:

```
public static class HistoryUtil {
    public static HistoryStorage AppHistory = new HistoryStorage();
}
```

The `History` class is now called `HistoryStorage` and it contains the observable collection just as before:

```
public class HistoryStorage  {
    public ObservableCollection<HistoryRecord> UserHistory { get; set; } =
        new ObservableCollection<HistoryRecord>();
}
```

The `xaml` code from before stayed the same.
I updated the `C# code` for the tab as follows:

```
public partial class HistoryTab : UserControl {
    public HistoryTab() {
        InitializeComponent();
        HistoryGrid.ItemsSource = HistoryUtil.AppHistory.UserHistory; 
        HistoryGrid.Items.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Timestamp", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
        HistoryGrid.Items.Refresh();
    }
}
```

This updated code does not sort the items.
This code shows the items but without the ascending order of the timestamp.
I can't figure out how and why the view is not sorted ascendingly according to the timestamp.
This is basically the same code, there are only a few changes to the structure and the fact that I've changed the `static` instance to be `non-static`.

---

Here are some sample data that demonstrates the issue:

```
HistoryRecord action1 = new HistoryRecord() {
    Sender = TransactionSender.User,
    Timestamp = DateTime.Now,
    Description="First record, should appear last"
};
action1.StoreRecord();

//After few seconds...

HistoryRecord action2 = new HistoryRecord() {
    Sender = TransactionSender.User,
    Timestamp = DateTime.Now,
    Description="Second record, should appear first"
};
action2.StoreRecord();
```

Where the `StoreRecord` method is set like this:

```
//For the static class:
public void StoreRecord() {
    History.UserHistory.Add(this);
}

//For the non-static class:
public void StoreRecord() {
    HistoryUtil.AppHistory.UserHistory.Add(this);
}
```

This is the History DataGrid:
[image: History DataGrid]

Please note this isn't about ascending or descending - I tried them both.
It just doesn't seem to sort the items anymore.
I added a breakpoint at `HistoryGrid.Items.SortDescriptions` and it doesn't seem to get there.

---

I would appreciate your help figuring out the problem.

Comment: Your issue is not reproducible: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. You forgot to include any sample data that demonstrates that the sorting is not working. It should work the same as before.

Comment: I updated my question to include sample data